# PHP gettext not working with me

Tags: php, gettext

The language path is :

> locale\es_ES\LC_MESSAGES\myapp.po and .mo

I used this class https://github.com/oscarotero/Gettext.

```
include_once "gettext/autoloader.php";

$locale = 'es_ES'; 

use Gettext\GettextTranslator;

//Create a new instance
$t = new GettextTranslator();

//It detects the environment variables to set the locale, but you can change it:
$t->setLanguage('es_ES');

//Load the domains:
$t->loadDomain('myapp', 'Locale');
//this means you have the file "project/Locale/gl/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po"

//Now you can use it in your templates
echo $t->gettext('My Name');
```